# Send Laravel logs from Supervisor to cloudwatch

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Laravel based queue system running on AWS worker tier. I am running the listener process using Supervisor and with the following configuration.

```
[program:program-name]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work --tries=1 --queue=cron_default_dev
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Everything is working fine except for the logging. I use CloudWatch to log and is using this [package](https://github.com/pagevamp/laravel-cloudwatch-logs). I have configures Laravel commands to execute at different schedules. The logging is working fine for some time and then it is working only in the command file. From the command file I am dispatching jobs as follows:

```
$job = (new MyJobCalss($this->argument()))
            ->onQueue(config('queue.connections.sqs.queue'));

        $this->dispatch($job);
```

There is a `stdout_logfile=/var/app/current/storage/worker.log` entry in the supervisor config. How can send these logs to CloudWatch?

Comment: you can use awslogs for this purpose `sudo yum install awslogs` then configure the log path in  `/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf`. https://medium.com/tensult/to-send-linux-logs-to-aws-cloudwatch-17b3ea5f4863

Comment: It is working when I changed the path to Laravel storage logs path. But then stops working after some time.

Comment: did you check permission, also check the logs of `aws-log`. you may see the reason